# Issue with querySelector 'tbody > tr[data-index=-1]'

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I have the following query selector. Using Chrome 38 I get a "SYNERR: Is not a valid selector" .. Now the interesting thing is that in CSS it works fine.

```
tbody > tr[data-index=-1]
```

Any ideas why JavaScript doesn't like that path?

Comment: how about tr[data-index="-1"], with quotes ?

Comment: Are you sure it works fine in CSS? It should be invalid either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, in [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs),

> Attribute values must be identifiers or strings

But `-1` is not a valid [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (emphasis mine):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a **hyphen followed
>   by a digit**.

Therefore, you must use a [string](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings):

> Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single
>   quotes.

For example,

```css
tbody > tr[data-index="-1"]
```

Comment: I guess I just had my DOH moment! Of course .. sometime we can't see the simpliest things